# What does "to give someone boners" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I ran across a strange hypothetical query in the youtube video *Why Kabaneri FAILS as an Attack on Titan Clone* by Gigguk, [around the five minute mark](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlEqbOok5wI&feature=youtu.be&t=4m48s): "Are back Muscles supposed to give me boners?"

When I looked up "boner" in dictionaries, the definition is "a stupid mistake" which doesn't fit in the context.

Comment: A boner is an erection. It's also a word for mistake.   https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/boner

Comment: There are millions of google hits on "boner" that answer this question, including various dictionaries.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇, of course there would be "boner" on google, I apologize I didn't add the context

Comment: @NhuThaiSanhNguyen Could you again edit your question to address the necessity of a dictionary search? "When you searched for *boner* in dictionaries, why don't they give you enough information?"

Comment: @NhuThaiSanhNguyen At this point, I doubt the other members will be satisfied until you at least tell us *which* dictionary you checked, and why you were unable to deduce the answer you already indicated was correct from it.

Comment: @Tonepoet , I checked google and lacviet dictionary, but I doubt anyone here would know lacviet unless he's Vietnamese. I know I got the correct answer from Leaky because I could vaguely guess what it means, I wanted a clear definition. Also, Leaky Nun gave that right answer before the original post was edited by anyone, so I don't think my question was that bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A "boner" is a term for male penis erection.

To "give someone a boner" means to sexually excite someone, esp. a male.

Comment: I think that's the right answer, it fits the context